# How to Multiple models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

> ```
> public class Student
>     {
>       public string Name;
>       public int Age;
>     }
>
>  List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>
>  {
>    new Student{ Name = "Handri", Age = 8 },
>    new Student{Name = "Jon Galloway", Age = 10},
>    new Student{ Name = "Scott Hanselman", Age = 9}
>  };
>
> public class Teacher
>   {
>   public string Name;
>   public int Age;
>   }
>
>  List<Teacher> TeacherList = new List<TeacherList>
>  {
>    new TeacherList { Name = "Jhon", Age = 30 },
>    new TeacherList {Name = "JANE", Age = 25},
>    new TeacherList { Name = "Peter", Age = 27}
>  };
> ```

i need multiple view in my models ;

..........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Don't use "dynamically", it's a buzzword. Explain what you are trying to do exactly. Are you looking for a `foreach()` loop? Do you mean `Student` where there's `Blog` in your code?

Comment: i use @model dynamic

                                      `<tbody>
                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                 @Html.DisplayFor(m=> item.Name)`

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i need add the title in grid from model `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => model.name)`

Comment: Do you have **2** data types in your list?

Comment: yes i have two model 
i need multiple model in one view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Tuple

A Tuple object is an immutable, fixed-size and ordered sequence object. It is a data structure that has a specific number and sequence of elements. The .NET framework supports tuples up to seven elements.

Using this tuple object we can pass multiple models from the controller to the view.

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult IndexTuple()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to my demo!";
    var tupleModel = new Tuple<List<Teacher>, List<Student>>(GetTeachers(), GetStudents());
    return View(tupleModel);
}

View Code

@using MultipleModelInOneView;
@model Tuple <List<Teacher>, List <Student>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2> 
<p><b>Teacher List</b></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Teacher teacher in Model.Item1)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@teacher.TeacherId</td>
            <td>@teacher.Code</td>
            <td>@teacher.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<p><b>Student List</b></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Enrollment No</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Student student in Model.Item2)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@student.StudentId</td>
            <td>@student.Code</td>
            <td>@student.Name</td>
            <td>@student.EnrollmentNo</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

More details to refer this link
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/